# How to make two transform operations in one XmlQuery?

Tags: xquery

could someone please give me example, how to make two XmlQuery tranformation, one after another?
I have XML column in database and it contains two sequences of subnodes. I need to make replacement in both sequences. Both sequences are placed on the same nest level.

It works ok if i make two xmlquery operations.
But the matter is I need to traverse my table per row and make UPDATE. So, I'd prefer to have 1 XmlQuery not to make two update cycles.

Comment: How do your queries look like? Post your code and surely somebody will help you.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39957296/xmlquery.sql - i can't make subsequent "if" checks in "return" statement... Have no idea what to do :(

Comment: for sure, that would not work - that's why i think about 2 SUBSEQUENT transform operation for each loop. But when I split these two cycles in 2 transform operation - I get "unexpected token transform" error on second transform (for tsmServer)

Comment: I managed to do this. I had to use all modify operations within parentheses, separated by comma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use all modify operations within parentheses, separated by comma.

Answer is a modified sql on dropbox:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39957296/xmlquery.sql